# (AWS) Can't launch RDS in my chosen VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm following AWS's instructions [Scenario 2: VPC with Public and Private Subnets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html#VPC_Scenario2_Implementation) and am having issues at the point I try to launch a DB server.

When I launch my instance, all is fine and I am able to assign it to my newly created VPC.  However, when it comes to launch the RDS, the only VPC available (on step 4, configure advanced settings) is the default VPC (ie not the one I created as per their instructions).

Has anyone any idea about this or indeed how to resolve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RDS requires a little more setup than an EC2 instance if you want to launch it within a VPC.

Specifically, you need to create:

- a DB subnet group within the VPC
- a VPC security group for the RDS instance

The documentation is a little buried in the AWS RDS documents. It can be found here:

[Creating a DB Instance in a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html)

Comment: Have no idea why they fail to mention this in the implementation, but am partly on my way to getting this sorted.  Thanks,